# How to get data from a web service with Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im trying to get data using Angular 
and I am trying to call a CurrencyConverter method as shown at this address: http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=10

My code does not work:

please help me.....

Thank You

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){ 

$http({
method : "GET",
url : "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=USD"
}).then(function mySucces(response) {
$scope.myWelcome = response.data;
}, function myError(response) {


$scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;});});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<p>Today's welcome message is:</p>
<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>
</div>
```

Output

Notfound

Comment: How exactly does it not work?

Answer (score 1):

The api endpoint appears to be giving a cross origin error, the `response.statusText` also ends up being empty so you can't tell that the http call errored out in your app.  If you change the error message to some string you'll see http call comes back.